# Question on Implicit Euler Method Proof

Tags: chain-rule, eulers-method

I'm working on a proof for the local truncation error of the implicit Euler method. I've been given a little hint to get started, but I'm stuck on a line that involves the chain rule. Can some please explain to me how this works out?
Given:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y),\;\;y(0) = y_{0},\;\;$ and $u_{n+1} = u_{n} + hf(u_{n+1})$

If I have $$f(y_{n+1}) = f(y_n) + f_{,y}(y_{n+1}-y_n) +  higher\,order\,terms $$

How does that become $$f(y_{n+1}) = f(y_n) + f_{,y}\,hy' + O(h^2) $$
Specifically, how do you get the $\,f_{,y}\,hy'\,$?

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. What does $f_{,y}$ stand for?

Comment: My apologies, I had a typo. I've tried to make it a little more clear. Also, $f_{,y}$ is the derivative of f with respect to y, i.e. $\frac{df}{dy}$